# r shiny DT: rownames=FALSE disables programmatic row selection

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I've got a programmatic row selection 'feature' in a shiny app I'm building.  Users drop markers by clicking on a map, and the rendered datatable displays information about the marker.  When a user clicks on an existing marker, the applicable entry in the datatable is selected (and highlighted by default).

I've found that when using `rownames=FALSE`, the programmatic row selection functionality seems to be disabled.  It works fine as long as this option isn't used, but then I get the undesired effect of the rownames column showing up in the datatable.  Wondering if I'm doing something wrong...

In the code below, `rv$markers` is a reactive variable that stores information about markers.  `selectedMarker` is the row.name of the `rv$markers` row corresponding to the clicked-on marker.

```
updateMarkerList <- function(selectedMarker=NULL) {

  output$markerList <- DT::renderDataTable(

    expr = {
      if(!(nrow(rv$markers))) return() # No rendering if no markers

      data <- rv$markers[,c("id","lat","lng","juris")]
      data
    },

    selection=list(mode='single', selected=as.character(selectedMarker)),
    #rownames=FALSE #rows will not be selected when markers are clicked if this is "on"
    style="bootstrap",
    class="compact",
    caption='Marker List',
    options=list(dom='tp'),
    colnames=c("ID","Lat","Lon","City")

  )

}
```

Comment: Just a guess, try making a reactive `datatable` with all the parameters like `rownames` set that you pass to `renderDataTable` rather than doing the data steps and the datatable options all in one renderDataTable